# Javascript concatenate select and input values in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, concatenation

I'd like to concatenate several values from selects and input fields on a final input field that contain all the values.

What I have until now is this:

```js
$('#chosen_a').change(function() {
  $('#ddlNames').val($('#chosen_a option:selected').data('id'));
  console.log($('#chosen_a option:selected').data('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="criteria_title" id="chosen_a" data-placeholder="Select Category" class="chzn_z span3 dropDownId chzn-done" style="display: block;">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">- First select -</option>
  <option value="AAA" data-id="AAA">AAA</option>
  <option value="BBB" data-id="BBB">BBB</option>
  <option value="CCC" data-id="CCC">CCC</option>
  <option value="DDD" data-id="DDD">DDD</option>
  <option value="EEE" data-id="EEE">EEE</option>
</select>

<input id="Something1" placeholder="Write something"></input><br/>

<select name="criteria_title" id="chosen_b" data-placeholder="Select Category" class="chzn_z span3 dropDownId chzn-done" style="display: block;">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">- Second select -</option>
  <option value="FFF" data-id="FFF">FFF</option>
  <option value="GGG" data-id="GGG">GGG</option>
  <option value="HHH" data-id="HHH">HHH</option>
  <option value="III" data-id="III">III</option>
  <option value="JJJ" data-id="JJJ">JJJ</option>
</select>

<input id="Something2" placeholder="Write something else"></input><br/>

<br><br>

<input maxlength="2600" name="ddlNames" id="ddlNames" onKeyUp="countChar(this)" placeholder="Blocco Note"></input><br/>
```

In effect, I can get the first select option to the input field, but I do not know how to add the rest.

Comment: You have `$("#chosen_a ...` for the first value - why can't you use `$("#chosen_b ...` for the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const onChange = () => {
  const value = $('#chosen_a option:selected').val() + ' '
    + $('#Something1').val() + ' '
    + $('#chosen_b option:selected').val() + ' '
    + $('#Something2').val();

  $('#ddlNames').val(value);
}

$('select').change(onChange);
$('input').keydown(onChange);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well ...

Add a class 'getValues' to all inputs & selects that you want to get the values and create an event on JQuery onChange so when something will change it will auto-join it in that #ddlNames input.

```
$('.getValues').change(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('.getValues').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#ddlNames').val(values.join(', '));
})
```

Comment: Consider using [map()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) which does the same as your code but without the array initialisation / push.